# InnerHTML Property Appending Instead of Replacing Data

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm trying to create a real time matched-data displayer. (ie, I have an array of data, when a user enters a string on the text box, the matched strings from the array will be displayed).

But here a small problem occured, when I try to display the new matched-data , the old data is also appending with the result.

> for eg,
>   assume that the array is => ['abcd','aaa','bcd','aabb']

I). First I entered the letter 'a'

then the **output** will be

```
 - abcd
 - aaa
 - aabb
```

II). Then I add one more letter 'aa'

**Output Expected:**

```
 - aaa
 - aabb
```

**Output Returned** By Program:

```
- abcd
- aaa
- aabb
- aaa
- aabb
```

Here Is the code

```js
var elemContainer = ['abcd','aaa','bcd','aabb'];
var matchedItems = [];
var result = '';

function showSearchData(){
  document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
  /*console.log(this.value);*/
   var data = this.value;
   for(let i=0;i < elemContainer.length; i++){
    if(elemContainer[i].includes(data)){
      matchedItems.push(elemContainer[i]);
    }
   }
   result = '';
   console.log(result);
   displayMatchedData();
  });
}

function displayMatchedData(){
  /*result = '';*/
  document.getElementById('matched-items-container').innerHTML = '';
  for(let i=0;i<= matchedItems.length;i++){
    result += '<li>'+matchedItems[i]+'</li>';
  }
  document.getElementById('matched-items-container').innerHTML = result;
}


showSearchData();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" />
<ul id="matched-items-container"></ul>
```

What I have tried so far 
I. Reset the result variable every time whenever a `keyup` event is happened.
II. Set the `element.innerHTML` to NULL every time the display() is called.

Comment: Hello! You are forgetting to clear the `matchedItems` array, before pushing new values. Just add `matchedItems = [];` right before the `for` in *showSearchData();*.

Comment: @AlainCruz yup, tnx for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear your `matchedItems` array every `keyup` action, also your counter starts from 0 , so this line `for(let i=0; i<= matchedItems.length; i++)` must be without `=` or it will give you `undefined`

```js
var elemContainer = ['abcd','aaa','bcd','aabb'];
var matchedItems = [];
var result = '';

function showSearchData(){
  document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
  
  matchedItems = [];
  
   var data = this.value;
   for(let i=0;i < elemContainer.length; i++){
    if(elemContainer[i].includes(data)){
      matchedItems.push(elemContainer[i]);
    }
   }
   result = '';
   console.log(result);
   displayMatchedData();
  });
}

function displayMatchedData(){
  /*result = '';*/
  document.getElementById('matched-items-container').innerHTML = '';
  for(let i=0;i< matchedItems.length;i++){
    result += '<li>'+matchedItems[i]+'</li>';
  }
  document.getElementById('matched-items-container').innerHTML = result;
}


showSearchData();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off" />
<ul id="matched-items-container"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to clear the `matchedItems` array.

```js
var elemContainer = ['abcd','aaa','bcd','aabb'];
var matchedItems = [];
var result = '';

function showSearchData(){
  document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
  /*console.log(this.value);*/
   var data = this.value;
   
   // here, clear the matched items array
   matchedItems = [];

   for(let i=0;i < elemContainer.length; i++){
    if(elemContainer[i].includes(data)){
      matchedItems.push(elemContainer[i]);
    }
   }
   result = '';
   console.log(result);
   displayMatchedData();
  });
}

function displayMatchedData(){
  /*result = '';*/
  document.getElementById('matched-items-container').innerHTML = '';
  for(let i=0;i<= matchedItems.length;i++){
    result += '<li>'+matchedItems[i]+'</li>';
  }
  document.getElementById('matched-items-container').innerHTML = result;
}


showSearchData();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" />
<ul id="matched-items-container"></ul>
```